# Is it true that if $f$ is strictly convex and $d$ a metric, then $f\circ d$ is not a metric?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

As I was studying functional analysis, this question came to my mind. Let $X$ be a metric space with metric $d$. Is it true that for any function $f$ strictly convex, then $f(d(x,y))$ is not a metric? What about crescent and convex and $f(0)=0$?

I tend to think it’s true, since I can easily show that for $f(x)=x^2$ then $f\circ d$ is not a metric.

Comment: I'm not sure about your case, but there's a lemma that my professor Dr. Yoon had mentioned (if I remember correctly, he said that he created it), that says the following. If f is concave and f(0) = 0, then f \circ d is a metric whenever d is a metric.

Comment: Yeah, I can prove something similar for sub-additive. But any idea about this contrary proposition?

Comment: Not any function. Consider $f(x)=x^2 +1$ and note that $f(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks, I’ve updated.

Comment: What do you mean by crescent?

Comment: $x>y \implies f(x)>f(y)$

Comment: @Will it means increasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Take $X=\{0,1\}$, and set $d(0,1):=1$. Then each function  $f$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)>0$ will create another metric $f\circ d$ on $X$.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder if the underlying space has more structure, if it then becomes true.